# How do I install Gitlab on a VM?

Tags: gitlab, vmware

I installed Gitlab on a VMWare VM, using NAT, where the VM is running Ubuntu 16.04.  Everything installed OK, but I can't access it via the browser.  It says I need to configure an external URL.  I only need to access the VM from my Mac (where the VM is running).  How do I configure a URL so I can access it from my Mac?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the VM is running locally on the Mac in NAT network config, this means that the ports are available directly on the Mac IP.  If you only need to access it from the Mac itself, you could access the application at the port via the loopback (local only) IP 127.0.0.1

If gitlab is running on port 80 in the VM, on the Mac you should be able to access with http://127.0.0.1
If this doesn't work, there are a few options:

Confirm no other service/webserver is running on port 80 locally on the Mac.  If there is, you should change the port of the gitlab webserver in your VM, and access using http://127.0.0.1:port

Confirm that port 80 is allowed in the VM firewall, and that the webserver is running  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-gitlab-on-ubuntu-16-04